# How can I invoke methods which are not specified on the IDL interface ? [Corba, JAVA]

Tags: java, corba, idl, distributed-transactions, jacorb

My IDL looks like :

```
interface TransactionResource {
    void prepare() raises (NotPreparedException);
    void commit() raises(TransactionException);
    void rollback() raises(TransactionException);
};
```

When i implement the TransactionResourceImpl, I implement an other Java interface "ManageDemand" like this:

```
public class TransactionResourceImpl extends TransactionResourcePOA implements ManageDemand {
    // In this class, I redefine TransactionResource methods, and ManageDemand methods.
}
```

When I send this object TransactionResourceImpl to client, he can just use the TransactionResource methods and not ManageDemand methods.

I tried to use the reflexion to invoke ManageDemand methods, but it's not possible.

How can the client invoke ManageDemand methods, on the TransactionResourceImpl distributed reference?

Comment: You can't, by definition. The mechanism for exposing the remote methods is IDL. If it isn't in the IDL, it isn't exposed as a remote method. Your question doesn't make sense,

Comment: Is that methods remote or local?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. You'll have to add those methods to the IDL and implement them as you would any other CORBA object.